# Get json values using awk or jq

Tags: json, awk, jq

My json files looks like this.

i have more than 5000 files :
filename : **xxxx.json**

example file **1000.json**

```
[
  {
    "gender": {
      "value": "Female"
    },
    "age": 38.58685,
    "age_group": "adult"
  },
  {
    "gender": {
      "value": "Male"
    },
    "age": 26.64953,
    "age_group": "adult"
  }
]
```

example file **2000.json**

```
[
  {
    "gender": {
      "value": "Male"
    },
    "age": 63.8272,
    "age_group": "adult"
  },
  {
    "gender": {
      "value": "Male"
    },
    "age": 11.8287,
    "age_group": "child"
  }
]
```

Desired Output in one file **output.txt**

`1000 & Female,Male & 38,26 & adult,adult` 
 `2000 & Male,Male & 63,11 & adult,child`

Comment: What did you try? What specific bug did you encounter, or what specific part of the task did you have trouble implementing yourself? Right now this just reads as a request for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: im tryin to get output to import it to my database using delimiter &

Comment: i try this but i cant find how i can add filename at start of each line, and how i can separate values ` cat * | jq -j '.[].gender.value, .[].age, .[].age_group, []  '| sed 's/\[\]/\n/g'  `

Comment: In the future, please include that information (about what you tried and where you got stuck) in the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's doable in `jq` with some string interpolation:

```
$ find . -name "*.json" -exec jq -r \
  '(input_filename | gsub("^\\./|\\.json$";"")) as $fname |
   (map(.gender.value) | unique | join(",")) as $genders |
   (map(.age|floor|tostring) | join(",")) as $ages |
   (map(.age_group) | unique | join(",")) as $age_groups |
   "\($fname) & \($genders) & \($ages) & \($age_groups)"' '{}' +
1000 & Female,Male & 38,26 & adult
2000 & Male & 63,11 & adult,child
```

The `input_filename` command returns the obvious, and for the other parts, just grab the needed fields from `.` as an array and join them into CSV strings (Using `join` instead of `@csv` to avoid added quotes).

---

The `find` stuff is to avoid the possibility of just `jq -r '...' *.json` being too long a command line, since you said you have more than 5000 files. It runs `jq` potentially multiple times, with as many filenames as possible each time (The trailing `+` instead of `;` makes `-exec` work a lot like `xargs`), instead of running it once per file, for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: @Cyrus It also has `ceil`, `round`, `nearbyint` and the other C99 rounding functions, depending on how you want to convert/round.

Comment: how can remove duplicate value? from this 

`1000 & Female,Male & 38,26 & adult,adult 
2000 & Male,Male & 63,11 & adult,child`

to  

`1000 & Female,Male & 38,26 & adult
2000 & Male & 63,11 & adult,child`

Comment: @DavidBoe You can add `unique` into the relevant filter.

Comment: @DavidBoe Between creating the array of strings and joining the elements... `map(.gender.value) | unique | join(",")`

Comment: @DavidBoe I refactored it a bit to make it more human-readable and avoid the huge long string. Added `unique` too.